# Inherit methods for adding to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I hope you can help me.

I'm working on a "Introduction to programming" Java-project for school, and have a little problem with inheritance.

I need to create methods for adding different products to an arraylist, that represents a very simple database. And so, i have an arraylist for cupcakes, one for bread etc.

How can I create a method in my superclass 'Product', that all the subclasses can inherit.

Right now the 'Add product' is implemented in every subclass, and looks something like this.

```
protected void addCakes() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    System.out.println("Enter quantity to be added: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    if(n > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cupcakedatabase.addCupcake(this);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The amount has to be positive");
    }
}
```

and the code in the cupcakeDB looks likes this:

```
private static ArrayList<Cupcake> cupcakes;

public CupcakeDB() {
    cupcakes = new ArrayList<Cupcake>();
}

public void addCupcake(Cupcake cupcake) {
    cupcakes.add(cupcake);
}
```

*EDIT*

This in my product class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Product {

protected String name;
protected String flavor;
protected double price;
protected int quantity;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public void createProduct(String name, String flavor, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.price = price;
}

public void changePrice(double price) {
    this.setPrice(price);
}

public void changeFlavor(String flavor) {
    this.setFlavor(flavor);
}

public void setFlavor(String flavor) {
    this.flavor = flavor;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFlavor() {
    return flavor;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
```

}

Comment: could you post your Product class?

Comment: Hi k0ner, added the product class now. Thx for reply.

Answer (score 1):

**you can try Something like,**

```
class Product<T>{
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(); 

    public void add(T t){
        list.add(t);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getMyAllProduct(){
          return list;
    }
}
```

> Now Inherit this to your specific Product class and will get you it automatic.